# Angular Karma - Error: No provider for MdDialogRef

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I have an issue testing the `MdDialog` from angular material 2 components.  The issue is that my component (using `MdDialog`) is an entry component, I can't test it with the current `TestBed` configuration.  The current `TestBed` configuration does not have an `entryComponent` property.

I have tried all the options here  (I created a NgModule for testing, Overwrote the TestBed config and Other things I came up with) :  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760

I have also looked at the angular material 2 `MdDialog` code to see how the do the testing but I was not successful.

I have not been successful with any of them.  Has anyone been successful testing the Mdialog component in their application?  Can you share the option you implemented?

Here is my example code:

```
#Component

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MdDialogRef } from '@angular/material';

import { MessageService } from './../message.service';
import { MessageRequest } from './../message.model';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../core/authentication/authentication.service';
import { AuthenticationResponse } from './../../core/authentication/authentication.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-message-add',
  templateUrl: './message-add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./message-add.component.scss']
})
export class MessageAddComponent implements OnInit {
  messageAddForm: FormGroup;
  currentUser: AuthenticationResponse;
  disabled: boolean;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
              private dialog: MdDialogRef<MessageAddComponent>,
              private messageService: MessageService,
              private authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.messageAddForm = fb.group({
      'id': ['', Validators.required],
      'txt': ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.currentUser = this.authService.getUser();
    this.disabled = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onDateChange(value: any) {
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.dialog.close();
  }

  onMessageAdd() {
    const newMessage: MessageRequest = {
      user: this.currentUser.userId,
      message: {
        id: this.messageAddForm.value.id,
        txt: this.messageAddForm.value.txt,
      }
    };

    this.messageService.add(newMessage).subscribe((response) => {
      this.dialog.close();
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(`messageService.save: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
    });
  }

}

#Component Test

/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserModule, By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, DebugElement, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {
  MdButtonModule,
  MdToolbarModule,
  MdInputModule,
  MdMenuModule,
  MdSelectModule,
  MdIconModule,
  MdCardModule,
  MdDialogModule,
  MdOptionModule,
  MdDialog,
  MdDialogRef,
} from '@angular/material';
import { Md2Module } from 'md2';

import { MessageAddComponent } from './message-add.component';

describe('MessageAddComponent', () => {
  let component: MessageAddComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MessageAddComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MdButtonModule,
        MdToolbarModule,
        MdInputModule,
        MdMenuModule,
        MdSelectModule,
        MdIconModule,
        MdCardModule,
        MdDialogModule,
        MdOptionModule,
        Md2Module
      ],
      providers: [],
      declarations: [MessageAddComponent]
    }).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [MessageAddComponent],
      },
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessageAddComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create',
    inject([MessageAddComponent], (notificationAddComponent) => {
      expect(notificationAddComponent).toBeTruthy();
    }));
});
```

Comment: what you are actually looking for unit testing or implementation?

Comment: I have a component that uses mdDialogRef to get data for display and send it back to the caller.  I am looking for a way to test the component with MdDialog.   I get a "Error: No provider for MdDialogRef" when I run my test.  Like I said, I tried the options at this link:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760

Comment: update the post with your component code and corresponding unit test code

Comment: done, i added the component class and the class test

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet man. Actually i have not tried it again

Answer (score 1):

Look at source code of material how they test dialog They create a real module for testing and import it in TestBed. [dialog.spec.ts](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/dialog/dialog.spec.ts)

```
// Create a real (non-test) NgModule as a workaround for
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10760
const TEST_DIRECTIVES = [
  ComponentWithChildViewContainer,
  PizzaMsg,
  DirectiveWithViewContainer,
  ContentElementDialog,
  DialogWithInjectedData
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [MdDialogModule, NoopAnimationsModule],
  exports: TEST_DIRECTIVES,
  declarations: TEST_DIRECTIVES,
  entryComponents: [
    ComponentWithChildViewContainer,
    PizzaMsg,
    ContentElementDialog,
    DialogWithInjectedData
  ],
})
class DialogTestModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need import `import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';` in you test file.

add `MaterialModule` in your import array.

This fixed my issue.